# Is it possible to set a top-level only/except in a .gitlab-ci.yml file?

Tags: build, continuous-integration, gitlab

I have three stages in my CI file, they all have only/except like this:

```
test:
  only:
    - tags
  except:
    - branches
  script:
    - npm run test
```

Seems redundant to have the only/except in three places. Is there a way to set this at the top level of the script config? Don't see anything like that in the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#gitlab-ci-yml).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the map merging feature: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#special-yaml-features

```
.job_template: &job_definition
  only:
    - tags
  except:
    - branches

test1:
    <<: *job_definition
    script:
      - npm run test

test2:
    <<: *job_definition
    script:
      - # ...
```

Comment: Amazing feature!